# How to make click send to target _ blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This my code so what wrong from my code ? I don't know which side to blame for using Codepen.

```js
$('#kirim').click(function(){
var kosong = "";
  if($('#random').val() ==''){
    kosong = $('#random').attr('placeholder');
    alert('silahkan tulis ' + kosong);
    $('#random').focus();
    return false;
  } else if($('#nameFile').val() ==''){
    kosong = $('#nameFile').attr('placeholder');
    alert('silahkan tulis ' + kosong);
    $('#nameFile').focus();
    return false;
  }
var link1 = "http://dl.stickershop.line.naver.jp/products/0/0/1/",
    link2 = $('#random').val(),
    link3 = "/iphone/",
    link4 = $('#nameFile').val(),
    link5 = "@2x.zip";
  $(this).attr('href', + link1 + link2 + link3 + link4 + link5).attr('target','_blank');
  return false;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' name='' id='random' placeholder='Kode Unik'/>
<input type='text' name='' id='nameFile' placeholder='Nama File'/>
<input type='submit' name='' value='Download' id='kirim'>
```

please help me which part is the one? and sorry for my bad english language.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `+` before `link1` in this code `$(this).attr('href', + link1 + link2 + link3 + link4 + link5).attr('target','_blank');`. Here `+` before `link1` will act as unary plus and will try to convert the string to number and it will result in `NaN`. SO remove that `+` from the beginning

```js
$('#kirim').click(function() {
  var kosong = "";
  if ($('#random').val() == '') {
    kosong = $('#random').attr('placeholder');
    alert('silahkan tulis ' + kosong);
    $('#random').focus();
    return false;
  } else if ($('#nameFile').val() == '') {
    kosong = $('#nameFile').attr('placeholder');
    alert('silahkan tulis ' + kosong);
    $('#nameFile').focus();
    return false;
  }
  var link1 = "http://dl.stickershop.line.naver.jp/products/0/0/1/",
    link2 = $('#random').val(),
    link3 = "/iphone/",
    link4 = $('#nameFile').val(),
    link5 = "@2x.zip";
  $(this).attr('href', link1 + link2 + link3 + link4 + link5).attr('target', '_blank');
  return false;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' name='' id='random' placeholder='Kode Unik' />
<input type='text' name='' id='nameFile' placeholder='Nama File' />
<input type='submit' name='' value='Download' id='kirim'>
```